# Variable inside 2 while loops won't reset

Tags: c

Unless my computer is going crazy or I missed something. When I run the code the variable count does not reset to zero after each inner while loop. 
Ex. If I enter:
xxx
yyyy
Output of count is 1-9. But it should be 1-4 and 1-5.

```
int main(){

    char string[500][500];
    int letterWords[15]={0};

    printf("Enter several lines of text.\n");
    scanf("%[^\t]", string);

    int a=0, b=0;

    int count=0, i;

    while(string[a][0]!='\0'){
        while(string[a][b]!='\0'){
            count++;
            b++;
            printf("%d\n", count);
        }
        printf("\n");
        count-=2;
        letterWords[count]++;
        a++;
        b=0;
        count=0;  //the count doesn't reset to 0 for some reason
    }

    for(i=0;i<15;i++){
        if(letterWords[i]==0){
            continue;
        }
        printf("%d %d\n", i+1, letterWords[i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: This line `scanf("%[^\t]", string);` is broken. You should be able to detect this using a debugger

Comment: What happens when `a=1`? What is in `string[1]`? (this presumes `scanf` succeeded -- but without validating the **return** there is no way to know)

Comment: What happens if you move `if (scanf("%[^\n]%*c", string[a]) != 1) return 1;` immediately after `while(string[a][0]!='\0'){`?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike what you are thinking, the `scanf` only scans the line in the `string[0]`. 
The others are uninitialized. Trying to read them is undefined behavior.

Now again there is one thing you are doing passing `string` in `scanf`. Value wise it contains the same
value as that of `string[0]`. So it basically reads the lines in `string[0]`.

Assuming that the `scanf` didn't fail now you get into the while loop.
The first check is redundant. When you `a` is anything other than `0` then it will invoke undefined Behavior.

Counting the length via increasing `count`. Suprisingly then you try to increase value in `letterWords`.
When the value `count` is not `<=14` the again you access array index out of bound. Again this is undefined behavior.

Now after so many undefined behaviors the usual assignment of `count=0` is supressed.
Simply the program complains and then line is not executed even.(Maybe).

In order to get multiple lines use `fgets` and read each of the line (`\n`)seperated in different `string[i]`-s.
Then you based on the number of lines read you run the loop. Then everything will work fine.
`while(string[a][0]!='\0')` is not a agood way rather try a check based on numbers of line read.(In your case)

Also again `printf("%s",string[i])` will print each of the lines.

A better way to use `scanf()` is to check the return value of `scanf()`.

Answer (score 0):

I took the liberty to reshape the code (too many things to change otherwise)

```
int main() {

    char string[500][500];
    int letterWords[15]={0}; // max line length is 14
    int a,i,count;

    printf("Enter several lines of text (end with ^D).\n");
    for(a=0 ; a < 500 && fgets(string[a], 500, stdin) ;  a++) /* nothing */;

    for(i=0 ; i<a ; i++) {
        for(count=0 ; string[i][count] && string[i][count] != '\n' ; count++)  /* nothing */ ;
        printf("Line %d: %d\n", i, count);
        letterWords[count]++;
    }

    for(i=0 ; i<15 ; i++) {
        if(letterWords[i]) {
            printf("%d %d\n", i, letterWords[i]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Explanations:

```
for(a=0 ; a < 500 && fgets(string[a], 500, stdin) ;  a++) /* nothing */;
```

Use `fgets` to read lines of a given max length. The line counter is `a`.
To complete input, the user press <kbd>Control-D</kbd> (`EOF`) on a blank line.
`fgets` returns `NULL` when `EOF` is met (or an error occurred).

```
for(i=0 ; i<a ; i++) {
```

`i` is the index in `strings`, goes from `0` to `a-1`.

```
    for(count=0 ; string[i][count] && string[i][count] != '\n' ; count++)  /* nothing */ ;
```

No need of other variables. `count` counts the number of characters in the line, and stops whenever `\n` or `\0` is met.

```
    printf("Line %d: %d\n", i, count);
    letterWords[count]++; // Increment the line-counter
}
```

Note that no line should have more than 14 characters. Finally,

```
for(i=0 ; i<15 ; i++) {
    if(letterWords[i]) {
        printf("%d %d\n", i, letterWords[i]);
    }
}
```

Prints the result, `Length Number_of_lines_of_that_length`.

Answer (score 0):

When reading *lines of input*, use a *line oriented* input function such as `fgets` or POSIX `getline`. `scanf` is full of pitfalls just waiting for new C-programmers to fall into.

While your code, especially `linewords` is a bit hard to follow, you attempt to be capturing the length in it to print all lines with characters.

One thing you have to understand is putting one `scanf` up top -- will just read one input. That makes your nested loops a bizarre effort in futility. Instead, you need to move your read within your outer loop so you are reading one line of input each go-round (technical term).

Rather than using nested loops, simply use a single loop to loop continually taking user input until the user generates an `EOF` (<kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd> on windoze). There you simply validate the read (that the string actually fit in your allotted storage) and trim the trailing '`\n'` read and included in your buffer by the *line oriented* input function.

While you are free to store the length of each string in a separate array, for this exercise a simple call to `strlen` will suffice.

Putting it altogether, you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 500     /* if you need constants, define them */

int main () {

    int n = 0;                          /* strings index */
    char string[MAX][MAX] = { "" };     /* 2d array of char */

    printf ("\nenter several lines of text\n"
            "[ctrl+d (ctrl+z on windows) when done]\n\n");

    for (; n < MAX;) {      /* take input until n == MAX or user EOF */
        printf ("line[%2d]: ", n);              /* prompt for input */
        if (fgets (string[n], MAX, stdin)) {    /* read line */
            size_t len = strlen (string[n]);    /* get length */
            if (len && string[n][len - 1] == '\n')  /* check last char '\n' */
                string[n][--len] = 0;   /* overwrite with nul-terminating char */
            else {  /* line too long handle error */
                fprintf (stderr, "error: line too long '%d'.\n", n);
                return 1;
            }
            n++;    /* increment line index */
        }
        else {  /* handle EOF */
            printf ("\nall done!\n\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)         /* output each line read */
        printf ("string[%2d] (%3zu chars) : '%s'\n", 
                i, strlen (string[i]), string[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** if you goal was to skip zero-length strings, then simply adding a check of `if (strlen(string[i]))` before the final `printf` would be fine. (you can save it in a variable in the final loop to prevent calling it twice))

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/rdstrings2d

enter several lines of text
[ctrl+d (ctrl+z on windows) when done]

line[ 0]: my dog
line[ 1]: has fleas
line[ 2]: my cat is lucky, and
line[ 3]: has none
line[ 4]:
all done!

string[ 0] (  6 chars) : 'my dog'
string[ 1] (  9 chars) : 'has fleas'
string[ 2] ( 20 chars) : 'my cat is lucky, and'
string[ 3] (  8 chars) : 'has none'
```

Answer (score 0):

// try using this code this seems to work just fine as you want
  #include

int main(){

```
char string[500];
int letterWords[15]={0};

printf("Enter several lines of text.\n");
scanf("%[^\t]", string);

int a=0, b=0;
//printf("%s",string);
int count=0, i;

while(string[a]!='\0'){
    while(string[a]!='\n'){
        count++;
        a++;
        printf("%d\n", count);
    }
    printf("\n");
    count-=1;
    letterWords[count]++;
    a++;
    b=0;
    count=0;  //the count doesn't reset to 0 for some reason
}

for(i=0;i<15;i++){
    if(letterWords[i]==0){
        continue;
    }
    printf("%d %d\n", i+1, letterWords[i]);
}
```

}